# AngularJS API call error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: angularjs, resources, jsonp

I've searched all over for this because alot of people seem to be getting this error.  I know why i'm getting it - but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I'm using the Zoopla Property API - http://developer.zoopla.com/docs/read/Property_listings

The callback is jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK which returns the API in JSONP format.  But the error is encountered because Angular changes the JSON_CALLBACK to angular.callbacks._0

And the API then completely ignores the callback function name and returns JSON instead because it doesn't like the dot notation.

Is there any way round this error?

Comment: can you post your relevant code?

Comment: propertyApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope',  '$resource', function($scope, $resource){

 $scope.propertyAPI = 
 $resource("http://linktoAPI&jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK", {callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"}, {get: { method : "JSONP"}});

 $scope.propertyResult = $scope.propertyAPI.get({page_size : 10});

 console.log($scope.propertyResult);

}]);